# How can I add OR query in NHibernate between a property and a many to many?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a Document class which has a User Property which is the User who owns the document, but also I have a User List.  Users which have access to the document.  I am trying to create a query which will return documents which either I own or I have access to.

```
IList<Document> results = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Document))
                .CreateCriteria("Owner")
                .CreateCriteria("UserList")
                .Add(nh.Criterion.Restrictions.IdEq(obj.Id))
                .SetFirstResult(pageSize * page)
                .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
                .List<Document>();
```

This above is what I have tried so far but to no avail.  The structure of the Document class, shortened is:

```
public class Document : DomainObject<Document>{
     public Document(){
          UserList = new List<User>();
     }
     public virtual User Owner{get;set;}
     public virtual IList<User> UserList{get;set;}
}
```

I appreciate any guidance on this!!

Cheeers,

Andrew

EXAMPLE SQL I AM LOOKING FOR

```
declare @UserID uniqueidentifier

set @UserID = '37f7a55f-84c9-461b-a5b2-b412fe96932b'

select * from [Document] s
where s.UserID = @UserID
or exists(select * from DocumentUser su where su.userid = @UserID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post the SQL that would return what you want ? .

I'm thinking there is a subquery in there - a detached criteria might help in that case. Then adding it to the ICriteria like : Add(Subqueries....)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The above would mean that UserList is a property of Owner, but UserList is a Property of Document.  I get that as an error too.

could not resolve property: UserList of: uk.co.andrewrea.BusinessLogic.Domain.Owner

Comment: I have updated it with an example sql I am looking to recreate

Answer (score 1):

I did it!

Thanks for your help! That last comment you made and asking me for the sql made me looked at it again clear:  Here is the solution:

```
    var detached = DetachedCriteria.For<Document>()
        .CreateCriteria("UserList")
        .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
        .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(obj.Id));

    IList<Document> results = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Document),"s")
        .CreateAlias("s.User","u")
        .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Eq("u.Id", obj.Id), Subqueries.Exists(detached)))
        .SetFirstResult(pageSize * page)
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
        .List<Document>();
```

Comment: Glad you made it work :) . I just made a small sample app and came up with the exact same thing - you just beat me to it :P

Comment: I appreciate your time!!  :-)